# How to avoid loose data when I switch between two or more component by routing in angular7/8?

Tags: angular

I have 3 components and they are not father or child of each other and I toggle between them by routing, each one of them have a form inside, and I want to use form data of one inside another after toggle(by routing) to, but as component will destroy after toggle to somewhere else by routing the data of them will destroy too, so what can i do?
(I tried services but did not answered!)

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways:

1. Use Injectable object:

//Class

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GlobalDataService {
   public var1: number = 0;
   public var2: string = 0;
}

//Component 1

export class Component1 {

    constructor(public globalDataService : GlobalDataService ) {
      this.globalDataService.var1 = 1;
    }
}

//Component 2

export class Component2 {

    constructor(public globalDataService : GlobalDataService ) {
      console.log(this.globalDataService.var1) //Should logs 1;
    }
}
```

2. Create an Observable (But I think it is an overkill in this case)